# Split list of tuples where second elment is greater than threshold

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples

I have a list of tuples that I need to split, where every second element in the tuple is greater than 1, into a "list of lists of tuples". From those lists of tuples I am trying to calculate the difference between the first element of the first tuple in the new list, and the first element of the last tuple in the new list. Sorry if that seems confusing.

Take the following as an example:

```
zp = [(1.31, 0), (1.32, 0),
      (1.33, 0), (1.34, 0),
      (1.35, 1), (1.36, 2),
      (1.37, 3), (1.37, 4),
      (1.39, 5), (1.38, 6),
      (1.40, 7), (1.41, 8),
      (1.42, 9), (1.43, 10),
      (1.44, 0), (1.45, 0),
      (1.46, 0), (1.47, 0),
      (1.48, 1), (1.49, 2),
      (1.50, 3), (1.51, 4),
      (1.52, 0), (1.53, 0),
      (1.54, 1), (1.55, 2),
      (1.56, 3), (1.57, 4),
      (1.48, 0), (1.59, 0),
      (1.60, 0), (1.61, 0),
      (1.62, 1), (1.63, 2),
      (1.64, 3), (1.65, 4),
      (1.66, 0), (1.67, 0),
      (1.68, 1), (1.69, 2),
      (1.70, 3), (1.71, 4)]
```

From here I enumerate all positions where the second element of the tuple is > 1, and get sequences of indexes for `zp`:

```
enums = [j for j, k in enumerate(zp) if not k[1] in (0,1)]

enums 
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 19, 20, 21, 25, 26, 27, 33, 34, 35, 39, 40, 41]
```

Here is where I start to suspect that I am taking a wrong turn as I have been going around in quite a few circles. For example, using for loops to get the slices for `zp`:

```
for k in range(1, len(enums)):
    if enums[k] - enums[k-1] > 1:
        print "index k-1", k-1, "end if seq: emum[k-1]", enums[k-1], " --", "index k", k, "start if next seq: emum[k-1]", enums[k]
```

And then from there, slicing `zp` with the altered `enum` indexes...so there has to be a better way right?

Any suggestions welcome.

*EDIT

Expected outcome:

```
[(1.36, 2),(1.37, 3), (1.37, 4),(1.39, 5), (1.38, 6),(1.40, 7), (1.41, 8),(1.42, 9), (1.43, 10)],
[(1.49, 2),(1.50, 3), (1.51, 4)], 
[(1.55, 2),(1.56, 3), (1.57, 4)],
[(1.63, 2),(1.64, 3), (1.65, 4)],
[(1.69, 2),(1.70, 3), (1.71, 4)]]
```

Comment: You gave an example, which is great. But what is the expected output for your example? This information could make it much easier to understand what you want.

Comment: @thiagowfx Sorry, see edit.

Comment: No need to be sorry, that was just an advice. Glad your question is solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the results based on the condition that the second item of each tuple is > 1 (`lambda x: x[1] > 1`). This will return a group for each set of consecutive items for which that conditional has the same result (either `True` or `False`). We can then use a list comprehension to ignore the groups that were grouped because the conditional was `False` and convert the groups to a list where the conditional was `True`.

```
import itertools
A = [list(group) for val, group in itertools.groupby(zp, lambda x: x[1] > 1) if val]

# [[(1.36, 2), (1.37, 3), (1.37, 4), (1.39, 5), (1.38, 6), (1.4, 7), (1.41, 8), (1.42, 9), (1.43, 10)], 
#  [(1.49, 2), (1.5, 3), (1.51, 4)],
#  [(1.55, 2), (1.56, 3), (1.57, 4)], 
#  [(1.63, 2), (1.64, 3), (1.65, 4)], 
#  [(1.69, 2), (1.7, 3), (1.71, 4)]]
```

Comment: Excellent Suever, I must start digging into new methods instead of plundering along. Thank you.